# Where can I find a fiscal year to date and year over year chart of federal tax revenues?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am interested in analyzing the impact of the Tax Cuts and Jobs Act of 2017 on federal revenues so far in FY 2018.

Comment: The story cited the Bureau of Economic Analysis at the St. Louis Federal Reserve. https://finance.yahoo.com/news/hole-trump-economy-175730768.html?soc_src=hl-viewer&soc_trk=fb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right here: https://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/historical-tables/  More data than you will need. I find it better than the Fed numbers.

BTW 2018 is trending to be about $23 billion more in revenue (Table 1.1), part of which has been credited to the tax cuts, although there have been numerous pro-growth initiatives, so it's impossible to isolate causality.

The Treasury publishes monthly Treasury Statements.  But the organization leaves much to be desired.

https://www.fiscal.treasury.gov/fsreports/rpt/mthTreasStmt/mthTreasStmt_home.htm

Comment: For some reason, the link from the Whitehouse.gov homepage has been removed.  So you may want to bookmark or remember to search for historical tables.

Comment: So, there is no month detail? We only have two quarters of the new tax law in effect and 2018 projections don't give me any details.

Comment: @tnk479  Updated

Comment: The story linked by @ohwilleke above elaborates on other factors that may come into play, such as a push by some some producers to ship products overseas before tariffs take effect, which may just have the effect of moving revenues from one period to another.

Comment: In a 20 trillion dollar economy, tax revenue differences from some tariff changes would be relatively minor in impact wouldn't they?

Comment: I'd recommend adding the outlays and deficit changes if you're going to list the the revenue in your answer to get the full picture. Projected Revenue: +$24B, Projected Expenses: +$191B, Projected Deficit: $832B for an increase in the deficit of 25% over the 2017 deficit ($665B)

Comment: @Gramatik  No one asked about the deficit.